# Update a running docker image

Tags: docker

I have a website that is run via a docker image. One script updates the image periodically, and another loads the new image, effectively updating the site. For this last task, I call the following script as a cron task:

```
#!/bin/sh
DOCKER_USER="user"
DOCKER_APP="app:latest"
DOCKER_IMAGE="${DOCKER_USER}/${DOCKER_APP}"

docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker system prune -af
docker pull $DOCKER_IMAGE
docker run -t -d -p 80:80 $DOCKER_IMAGE &
```

However, while I have been working with this for a time, I dont feel this is the best way to do so, as sometimes might lead to errors eg. if something goes wrong when using docker pull, the page will not work.

Does anyone know a better way have an updated image running, while preventing to have an increasing number of old images saved (this is why the pruning step in the script)?

Comment: Why don't you setup a simple Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: @suren, did'nt know about it, but looks promising, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is to rearrange the set of commands so that the pull happens first, and the time while the container isn't running is minimized.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
DOCKER_IMAGE="user/app:${1:-latest}"

# Pull the image first; if it fails don't keep going
docker pull "$DOCKER_IMAGE"

# Stop and restart the container
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker run -t -d -p 80:80 "$DOCKER_IMAGE"

# Clean up
docker system prune -af
```

It can be cleaner to `docker run --name` the container with some known name, and use that name in the `docker stop` and `rm` commands.  This would avoid destroying other unrelated containers.

Another useful technique is to run some sort of load balancer in front of your containers.  In pure-Docker space [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/quick-start/) is a popular option; you can run your own load-balancing HAProxy or Nginx; you can use a cloud provider load balancer, like an Amazon ELB; or you can use a higher-level service like Kubernetes or Amazon ECS that provides this for you.  That lets you first start the new container, then stop the old one, with the load balancer managing service routing.

It's also common practice to try to avoid the `latest` tag or a similar fixed string.  In my sample script above I make the tag an optional command-line option.  This lets you easily roll back to a previous build, and it's basically required if you do move to Kubernetes or ECS.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable and actually works as expected. I really appreciate your feedback!